# Wordpress update operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I'm having an issue upgrading Wordpress, and my googling isn't uncovering a solution. Hopefully you lot can lend a hand.

**Issue**

I'm trying to update a site running Wordpress 3.7 to Wordpress 3.8.1 but it's throwing the below error upon pushing the "Update Now" button.

> Downloading update from https://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.8.1-new-bundled.zip…
>
> Download failed.: Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 736947 out of 6333109 bytes received
>
> Installation Failed

**Extra info**

- This is happening on my local MAMP development environment as the server doesn't have permission to do a live upgrade. I was hoping to run the upgrade, commit code changes and then push to server for testing.
- The zip file downloads fine when hitting "Download 3.8.1"
- Another, possibly related, issue is occurring on `Plugins > Add New > Popular` which also throws an error:

> An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.
>
> Try again

Comment: Do a manual update: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Comment: Is this on localhost ?

Comment: @ObmerkKronen yes this is on localhost

Comment: @RRikesh, that's more of a workaround than a solution. Anyway I did do that now but the exact same issue ('timed out after 5000 milliseconds') also occurs when trying to update each individual plugin.

Comment: Well.. I am having the same problems on localhost. Since 3.7 the whole update mechanism of core was changed, and it seems a bit buggy ( on localhost) Maybe someone needs to open a ticket on trac

Comment: Is it possible that your internet connection isn't fast enough to download wordpress.zip in less than five seconds? Hence a timeout. Have you tried increasing the maximum execution time?

Comment: Or maybe issues with permissions? Your webserver on your localhost can't write on your filesystem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting my hands dirty investigating in the Wordpress source, I was able trace the issue to a destructive filter in a plugin called "More Fields". I have disabled and uninstalled the plugin and the upgrades all work again.

**Details for those curious**

I tracked it down to this line in `WP_Http_Curl::request()`

```
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
```

The function's default timeout is 5, however `WP_Upgrader::upgrade()` actually calls the function via a download_package function passing in a 300 seconds timeout.

The culprit here was the plugin "More Fields" which included the following filter which broke the arguments array and therefore reset the default timeout:

```
// Prevent auto update to this custom plugin
add_filter( 'http_request_args', 'prevent_update_check', 10, 2 );

function prevent_update_check( $r, $url ) {
    if ( 0 === strpos( $url, 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/update-check/' ) ) {
        $my_plugin = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
        $plugins = unserialize( $r['body']['plugins'] );
        unset( $plugins->plugins[$my_plugin] );
        unset( $plugins->active[array_search( $my_plugin, $plugins->active )] );
        $r['body']['plugins'] = serialize( $plugins );
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Not sure if it is intentionally malicious. It looks like a targeted filter, but in the WP_Upgrader all the args are lost.